# is there a way to add one extra column to hibernate map of collection?

Tags: java, hibernate

In the below code, i have a map of collection entity that holds extra fields for my entities. I have been using like that for a long time in my project. 
Now, it is necessary to add one extra column to map. But, I want minimal changes in my code so it is the difficult part to solve. If i change the collection to one-to-many list or change the value of map to object, it comes with many refactoring issues and i lose the flexibility of map access etc...

Thanks for any helps and suggestions.

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "KEY")
@Column(name = "VALUE")
@CollectionTable(name = "ENTITY_X_EXTENSION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_X_ID"))
private Map<String, String> extensions = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring this should be the way to go. Very soon you will encounter another *Now, it is necessary to add...*

However, supposing that you are time pressured, you could change just the mappings (it's on a private field), and keep your existing getters and setters intact:

```
public Map<String, String> getExtensions() {
   Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
   for (...) {
      // Iterate through the changed mapping and read key/value pairs
      result.put(key, value);
   }
   return result;
}
```

This way the existing code would continue to work with the old entity API.

Comment: thank you Bozanovic, i have one more question, i define such collection entities at the owner side of relation and i have different table for my different entities, if i change the value of map with java object class, i lose this feature. in that case, does newly defined entity object that annotated with @Embeddable solve my problem?

Comment: You could try. However, I remember Hibernate had some bugs when embeddables are used as map values; maybe they fixed it. Anyway, if it does not work, you could use separate entities for the value (it can even be a `private static` nested class). Again, you could to it only in the mapping; you can transform different entity objects to the same value object in your accessors, so that the code that uses the entity always sees the same API.